# Documento word generado con pypandoc se muestra vacío

Tags: python, docx, pandoc

Estoy generando un archivo de word con pypandoc, lo guardo en una variable llamada output y luego hago un response donde mando esa variable para que el documento se descargue

```
logo = str(settings.BASE_DIR) + '/cv_api/templates/logoutpl.png'
context = {'listaFinal': listaFinal, 'docente': docente, 'logo': logo}

html_string = render_to_string('documento.html', context)

output = pypandoc.convert(source= html_string, format='html', to='docx', 
outputfile=str(Path.home() / "documento") + 'cv.docx', extra_args='--css=/templates/pdf_gen.css')
    
response = HttpResponse( output, content_type='application/msword')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="cv.docx"'

return response
```

Aqui hago el response `response = HttpResponse( output, content_type='application/msword')`, pero el documento se guarda en el lugar donde se indica en el outputfile `outputfile=str(Path.home() / "documento") + 'cv.docx'` En este directorio me descarga el documento con los datos, pero en el response me descarga un documento de word vació, como puedo hacer para que en el response me descargue el documento que se genera en la variable output. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por si a alguien le sirve para solucionar este problema tuve que cambiar el uso de `pypandoc` por una libreria llamada `python-docx-template` donde en base a un template se genera el documento `.docx` para ello lo hice de la siguiente forma:

```py
logo = str(settings.BASE_DIR) + '/cv_api/templates/logoutpl.png'
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/msword')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="cv.docx"'

doc = DocxTemplate(str(settings.BASE_DIR) + '/cv_api/templates/docx_filename.docx')
imagen = docente['foto_web_low'] 
myimage = InlineImage(doc, image_descriptor=logo, width=Mm(15), height=Mm(20))
context = {'listaFinal': listaFinal, 'docente': docente, 'var': logo, 'myimage': myimage}
doc.render(context)
doc.save(response)

return response
```

Esto me permitió generar el documento con la información necesaria.